# Integrating function pointer

Tags: c, function, pointers, function-pointers

I'm new to C and I ran into some problems understanding a part of the function below.

Shortly, it integrates a numerical R -> R function with the rectangle method:

```
double numint(double (*f)(double), double x1, double x2, double dx)
{
    double x, sum = 0;
    for (x = x1; x < x2; x += dx)
        sum += f(x) * dx;
    return sum;
}
```

My question is:

1.) What does `double (*f)(double)` stand for? How do I call this part of the function? Is it a type not defined in the example, or is it usable by itself?

For example, `exampledouble = numint( ?? , double1, double2, double3);`

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Also check out http://www.cdecl.org/. You can write some declaration that you don't understand and get an english translation or vice versa. For your particular statement, the translation was "declare f as pointer to function (double) returning double" :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`f` is a function pointer which requires a `double` as an argument and returns a `double`. So you have to pass in a function address using this prototype

`double myfunc(double);`

It is called here in this line:

```
sum += f(x) * dx;
```

Example:

```
 double myfunc(double v)
 {
    return v*v;
 }

 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
     double x1 = 1.0;
     double x1 = 2.0;
     double x3 = 5.0;

     double val = numint(myfunc, x1, x2, x3)
     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: A small detail to the OP: the function pointed to by `f` can be called with either `f(x)` of `(*f)(x)`.

Answer (score 3):

To add to the answer by Devolus, you call `numint` like this:

```
double parabola(double x) {
  return x * x + 3 * x + 1;
}

int main() {
  int ans = numint(parabola, 0, 3, 0.1);
  // gets integral from 0 to 3 of x^2 + 3x + 1

  // ...
}
```